# Is it possible to log how much memory a certain object is using in my app?

Tags: xcode, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating a game and I am wondering if it is possible to put a log in that would print out how much memory a certain object is using?

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. You can get the size of an instance of a class with an ObjC runtime method (objc_getInstanceSize). But it doesn't include the memory used by object references (id and pointer types) and memory allocated with malloc.

More details in my [blog post here.](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2013/01/memory-calculating-size-textures-audio-buffers-classes-collections/)